# How to fix width of tooltip at IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, tooltip

I've used [this tooltip](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip#view1) at my webpage. It works fine. But, I've noticed that it has a major problem at IE8 browser. At IE8, tooltip can't get it's full width. The, I've checked the original plugin's link at IE8 and I can see that it's the problem of that tooltip actually.

This is how it's come at all browsers:

[image]

And this is how it's come at IE8:

[image]

I've tried to fix it by css. But, I failed! I don't understand what's the problem. I've put the code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ2UD/) But, I can't load their js file from external resource path of jsfiddle. So, I've uploaded the js file to [another link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/8ac2a45hykn4ke8/tooltip.js) if it helps. How can I fix the problem of it at IE8?

Some CSS:

```
div#mcTooltipWrapper {position:absolute;visibility:hidden;overflow:visible;z-index:9999999999;top:0px;}
div#mcTooltip {float:left;border-style:solid;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: try putting max width and height to it

Comment: At which div, should I give max-width? I gave it to div#mcTooltip,
but, it didn't help. Besides that, max-width should be similar to javascript max-width property set on js file. Otherwise, it can't fit properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't know how to solve your problem within the tooltip creation method you're using, but I devised another method that does offer a fully customizable tooltip, also in IE8. And it is extremely lightweight:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo Lightweight Tooltip CSS + JS</title>
    <style>
    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
        }
    body {
        font: normal 1.3em Verdana;
        padding-top: 2em; /* creates space for the first tooltip in this demo */
        }
    span.tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
        }
    span.tooltip:hover {
        cursor: help;
        }
    span.tip {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        left: 0px;
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: .9em;
        border: 0px solid black; /* change as desired */
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 1px 5px;
        background: #eee;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#ccc));
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#eeeeee,EndColorStr=#cccccc);
        zoom: 1;
        visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The <span class="tooltip">WHO<span class="tip">World Health Organization</span></span> was established in 1948.</p>
    <p>
        It is part of the
        <span class="tooltip">UN
            <span class="tip">United Nations, <br>the successor of the <br>League of Nations</span>
        </span>,
        which was established in 1945.
    </p>
    <script>
        var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
        for (var i=0; i<tooltips.length; i++) {
            var tooltip = tooltips[i];
            if ('ontouchstart' in window || window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
                tooltip.onclick = function() {
                    if (this.children[0].style.visibility == '' || this.children[0].style.visibility == 'hidden')
                        this.children[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
                    else this.children[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }
            }
            else {
                tooltip.onmouseover = function() {
                    this.children[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
                }
                tooltip.onmouseout = function() {
                    this.children[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the live demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Aidcb?editors=100.

A couple of side matters:

- IE doesn't render the border-radius without an actual border.
- I made it so that on touchscreen devices one has to tap the tooltip element. I think that is the intuitive thing most, if not all, of those users will do.
- I set the width of the tips to `auto`, and regulated the actual width by means of `br`s in the tip's contents. You can also set a fixed width.
- If you also want 'bubble pointers', see http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/.

.
Let me know how you like it, if you will.

Comment: I've used another easy plugin. Still I'm accepting your answer. Thanks :)